# Can I say “He cries when slapped by his friend”

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

If it is correct, could you tell me what grammar topic should I review to develop my knowledge?

Comment: It's grammatically correct, but idiomatically unlikely in most contexts.

Comment: Are you talking about a one-off action or an habitual one?

Comment: It’s in the passive voice—readers much prefer the active voice: “He cries when his friend slaps him.”

Answer (score 1):

It's fine grammatically; you can interpret it in either of two ways: 
(a) a narrative - say, as part of a story ("When Charlie isn't looking he takes the fruit. He cries when slapped by his friend. He returns the fruit."); 
(b) as a type of (zero) condtional, equivalent to 'He cries whenever he is slapped by his friend'.

Suggested grammar topics: conditionals (especially the zero conditional); ellipsis (that is, the rules for omitting "he is" in the original sentence); the passive (his friend slaps him -> he is slapped by his friend)

Answer (score 0):

You can view it as a complex sentence. When (he is) slapped by his friend, he cries. "When (he is) slapped by his friend" is an adverbial dependent clause and modifies the independent clause "He cries." That the dependent clause is a passive construction is revealing. The sentence could be "When he slaps his friend, he cries." However, then you couldn't distinguish who it is that cries. An excellent case for the use of the passive.